# Add richtext field to a Touch UI Dialog - AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

I am setting up a dialog that has the following fields -
 1. A field to accept image as an input
 2. A field to accept a title
 3. A field that will accept richtext.

Please note that I do not want to enable inplace editing. I just want to add a richtext field (with all features enabled) in my dialog and use the data entered in this field in my component.

I am able to implement 1. and 2. but dont know how to go about 3.

Here is my code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Section Container"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
            type="nav"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <Styling
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                jcr:title="Styling"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <column
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <question_single
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldDescription="Please enter the Question"
                                fieldLabel="Question for Single"
                                name="./question_single"/>
                            <question_couple
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldDescription="Please enter the Question"
                                fieldLabel="Question for Couple Applicants"
                                name="./question_couple"/>
                            <page_header
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldDescription="Please enter page header"
                                fieldLabel="Page Header"
                                name="./page_header"/>
                        </items>
                    </column>
                </items>
            </Styling>
            <image
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                jcr:title="Image Properties"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
                    margin="{Boolean}false"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <column
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <file
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"
                                autoStart="{Boolean}false"
                                class="cq-droptarget"
                                fieldLabel="Image asset"
                                fileNameParameter="./image/fileName"
                                fileReferenceParameter="./image/fileReference"
                                mimeTypes="[image]"
                                multiple="{Boolean}false"
                                name="./image/file"
                                title="Upload Image Asset"
                                uploadUrl="${suffix.path}"
                                useHTML5="{Boolean}true"/>
                            <title
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldLabel="Title"
                                name="./image/jcr:title"/>

                        </items>
                    </column>
                </items>
            </image>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Please ignore the fields in the first tab. richtext field needs to be added to the second tab.

Please help!
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe recommends to use the richtext field using the InPlaceEditing/Full Screen Editing instead of adding the fields in the dialog as the complete functionality is covered by In-place/Full-screen editing.

[Click Here for the reference from Adobe Docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html).

> However, if you really wish  to use the RTE field inside your dialog, you can make use of the  **sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"** property to do the same.

See sample code below (the code refers to a richtext field in the touch UI dialog, simply put this piece of code in your touch UI dialog xml at the relevant place to make the dialog work).

```
<description
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"
    name="./rteTextPropertyName"
    useFixedInlineToolbar="{Boolean}true">
    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <subsuperscript
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="*"/>
        <format
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="*"/>
        <justify
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="*"/>
        <spellcheck
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="*"/>
        <misctools
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="[specialchars]">
            <specialCharsConfig jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <chars jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <copyright
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        entity="&amp;#169;"/>
                    <trademark
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        entity="&amp;#8482;"/>
                    <registered
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        entity="&amp;#174;"/>
                    <emDash
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        entity="&amp;#8212;"/>
                    <pound
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        entity="&amp;#163;"/>
                    <nbsp
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        entity="&amp;#160;"/>
                </chars>
            </specialCharsConfig>
        </misctools>
    </rtePlugins>
    <uiSettings jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <cui jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <inline
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                toolbar="[format#bold,format#italic,format#underline,#paraformat,image#imageProps,#justify,#lists,links#modifylink,links#unlink,findreplace#find,findreplace#replace,subsuperscript#subscript,subsuperscript#superscript,spellcheck#checktext,misctools#specialchars]">
                <popovers jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <justify
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        items="[justify#justifyleft]"
                        ref="justify"/>
                    <lists
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        items="[lists#unordered,lists#ordered,lists#outdent,lists#indent]"
                        ref="lists"/>
                    <paraformat
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        items="paraformat:getFormats:paraformat-pulldown"
                        ref="paraformat"/>
                </popovers>
            </inline>
        </cui>
    </uiSettings>
</description>
```

P.S.: I have added only a few RTE plugins keeping the length of the sample code in mind. You can add other plugins as needed.

> **Make sure to provide the correct context if reading the property in sightly (in here html), see below:**
>
> ### ${properties.rteTextPropertyName @context = 'html'}